# Maximum possible Score

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, dynamic-programming

I recently came across this question in a hiring challenge :

Given a directed graph of N(1 <= N <= 10^5) nodes and M(3 <= M <= 10^5) edges, the value of each node represents number of nodes reachable from that node. The score of graph is sum of values of all nodes in the graph. We need to remove **exactly 3 edges** from it such that the score of graph is maximum and return this maximum value.

My approach is to find a cycle and remove an edge from it. Repeat this same procedure if possible 3 times otherwise remove leaf. But I am not able to understand which edge to remove from cycle or which leaf to remove, or there is any other approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not an easy problem, if the graph were acyclic you could maybe do something with topological sort. Removing an edge from a cycle isn't always the best solution, e.g. for 5 nodes with edges [1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 2], removing edge 1 -> 2 gives a score of 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 = 12, but removing edge 5 -> 2 gives only a score of 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 10.

Comment: what about multi-edges (between same source and destination) and loops?

Comment: we are excluding those cases for now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the graph is fully connected and shall remain in that state:

1. If multiple edges between the same nodes are allowed, remove them first, since you do not reduce the score at all.
2. Remove edges, that point to the same node. By doing so, you will reduce the score of this node by 0/1,  depending on the interpretation.
3. All other edges will reduce the overall score of the graph by 2 (by 1 for each node). If you remove an edge of a cycle, the graph stays connected. What edge of the cycle you remove does not matter.

Comment: Can u please clearify 2nd point ? Also, after solving for first 2 cases, can we consider that answer will be (answer till now) - 2*(number of edges still to be removed) ?

Comment: in general, an egde connects two nodes n1 & n2. but if n1 equals n2, the node is pointing at itself.

Comment: If there are no multiple edges and self loops, what will be answer ? Will it be (current score) - 2*3 ?

Comment: How can single edge affect score by 2, score may decrease by more than 2 as well?